# Every X result different while fetch from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple php foreach loop which fetch some data from MySQL database

```
$result = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30");
$result->execute();
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    echo 'data';                            
}
```

As you can see there is LIMIT 30. Is it possible to to insert different data on every 10th result.`Data which is not from database`. It's static data and wont be changeable.  What I mean is something like

```
if ( $row=10 )
{
   echo $row['name'];
}
else
{
   echo '<div> some static text not from database </div>';
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print this static data **instead** of the row from the database (i.e., a total of 30 rows) or **in addition to it** (i..e, a total of 33 rows)?

Comment: Total 33 rows. 10 rows from database, 1 static, 10 from db, 1 static, 10 db, 1 static: `10-1-10-1-10-1`

Comment: you should add a variable to count, like `$i` which increments on each loop step... then use modulo 10 `%10`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i display text after every 10 rows of an SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257995/how-can-i-display-text-after-every-10-rows-of-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$counter = 0; //This is the counter which we will use to count row numbers.
$result = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 30");
$result->execute();
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $counter++; //We are incrementing the counter.
    echo $row['name'];
    //If we are at a row which is multiple of 10, we output a static value.
    if($counter % 10 == 0) 
        echo 'Hello World!';               
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$counter=0;
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $counter++;
    if($counter %10==0){} //10th result
    else{} //not 10th result
}
```

Comment: OP wants to output all rows fetched from table, and additional static values for every 10 rows. Your answer avoids to output results at 10th rows.

Comment: Yes, It doesn't return what I need.